# MySQLi multiple conditions, what's wrong

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to do prepared statements as follows:

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE from = '?' && to = '?' LIMIT 1");
    $stmt->bind_param('ii', $fromId, $toId);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($db_offeredAlready);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
```

I get the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /path/to/script.php on line 97
```

Adding ` and ' gives me

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `from` = '?' && `to` = '?' LIMIT 1");
```

and the following

```
 Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param() [mysqli-stmt.bind-param]: Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /path/to/script.php on line 97
```

Obviously the number of BIND vars match the number of ? marks.  I have tried all combinations of adding and removing ` and ' to no avail.  What's wrong with this prepared statement?  I can do a SELECT with one condition just fine, but it complains with multiple.

Comment: For the first example, you can't have a column called "from" because mysql interprets it as part of the statement.  Using the back ticks allows you to do that.  It is now just solving why the bind portion isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placeholders  (`?`) need not to be quoted.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `from` = ? && `to` = ? LIMIT 1");
```